# Count characters, words, and lines in files (wc in rust)

Tags: beginner, parsing, rust

I wrote a barebones version of `wc` in rust. `wc` is a program that counts the number of characters, words, and lines in a file and outputs those values to the command line. Here is an example of the output:

```
   9   25  246 Cargo.toml
  52  163 1284 src/main.rs
  61  188 1530 total
```

My version currently lacks the proper output alignment, and it doesn't print the total (it also lacks the command line options, and it panics when fed a directory). But I would like to get some feedback before I go any further.

```
use std::env;
use std::fs::read_to_string;

struct InputFile {
    words: u32,
    lines: u32,
    characters: u32,
    name: String,
}

impl InputFile {
    fn new(name: &String) -> Self {
        let content = read_to_string(name).unwrap();
        let (mut characters, mut words, mut lines) = (0, 0, 0);
        let mut spaced: bool = false;
        for c in content.chars() {
            if c as u8 != 0 {
                characters += 1;
            }
            if c != ' ' && c != '\n' {
                spaced = false
            }
            if c == '\n' {
                lines += 1;
                if !spaced {
                    words += 1;
                    spaced = true;
                }
            }
            if c == ' ' && !spaced {
                words += 1;
                spaced = true;
            }
        }
        Self { lines, words, characters, name: name.to_string() }
    }
}

impl std::fmt::Display for InputFile {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{} {} {} {}",
            self.lines, self.words, self.characters, self.name
        )
    }
}

fn main() {
    let files: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    for f in &files[1..] {
        println!("{}", InputFile::new(f));
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad I am not the only one doing this ;-) https://github.com/jonasthewolf/wc

Answer (score 1):

`InputFile` doesn't appear to be a file — a better name might be `Statistics`.

`usize` is conventionally used for indexes and sizes instead of `u32`.

[Don't take an argument by `&String`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/9716597)  Since the algorithm works for not only files but other streams of characters as well, consider taking a `BufRead` argument.

Reading the whole file into memory isn't efficient — an alternative is to use the [`utf8-chars`](https://docs.rs/utf8-chars/) crate to identify characters.

`c as u8 != 0` is just `c != '\0'`.

It took me a while to figure out what `spaced` does — `in_word` might be a better name.

[`char::is_whitespace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.is_whitespace) checks for all kinds of whitespace.

In `main`, [`Iterator::skip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.skip) allows you to skip one argument without allocating a `Vec`.

---

Here's my version:

```rust
use {
    anyhow::Result,
    parse_display::Display,
    std::{
        env,
        fs::File,
        io::{BufRead, BufReader},
    },
    utf8_chars::BufReadCharsExt,
};

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Display)]
#[display("{characters} {words} {lines}")]
struct Stats {
    characters: usize,
    words: usize,
    lines: usize,
}

impl Stats {
    fn new<R: BufRead>(mut reader: R) -> Result<Self> {
        let mut stats = Stats {
            characters: 0,
            words: 0,
            lines: 0,
        };
        let mut in_word = false;

        for c in reader.chars_raw() {
            let c = c?;

            if c != '\0' {
                stats.characters += 1;
            }

            if !c.is_whitespace() {
                in_word = true;
            } else if in_word {
                stats.words += 1;
                in_word = false;
            }

            if c == '\n' {
                stats.lines += 1;
            }
        }

        Ok(stats)
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    for path in env::args().skip(1) {
        let file = BufReader::new(File::open(&path)?);
        let stats = Stats::new(file)?;
        println!("{} {}", stats, path);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: nitpicking: what if the output doesn't end with `\n`, or with a space? In that case the number of words or the number of lines gets out wrong. It's typical for these kinds of counting problems to need another extra iteration at the very end, to finish the words and the lines.